# Delete each line containing ID from another file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a csv file (list.csv), which contain something like that:

```
"1","10","1","2"
"2","22","20","2"
"3","33","5","2"
"4","36","225","2"
"5","36","225","2"
```

I have another file (delete.txt):

```
"1"
"4"
```

I want to delete each line containing the ID from the delete.txt file.
In my example, I want to display:

```
"2","22","20","2"
"3","33","5","2"
"5","36","225","2"
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using grep in a single pass (you may add an `echo "$arg"` at the end if you want to see the query used) :

```
#!/bin/bash
arg=""
for i in `cat delete.txt`; do
        if [ -n "$arg" ]; then
                arg="$arg\|^$i"
        else
                arg="^$i";
        fi
done;
grep -v "$arg" input.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
< delete.txt xargs -I % sed -i '/%/d' list.csv
```

It reads all lines from delete.txt and pass is to sed for deleteting.

Comment: you don't need `-L 1` if you use `-I`.